# как получить строку файла в php без загрузки файла целиком

Tags: php

Проблема заключается в следующем: есть разные файлы с содержимым в виде списка из 60к строк в каждой и объемом около 7мб каждая.
Мне требуется получать определенную строку с определенного файла под конкретную страницу сайта (более 50к страниц).
Если использовать file(), то он каждый раз будет загружать весь файл целиком в массив и из массива уже брать конкретную строку. И каждый раз это вызывает нагрузки на сервер.

Хотелось бы снизить нагрузки. Есть ли способ брать нужную строку, если я знаю ее порядковое число, без загрузки файла целиком? Сейчас использую file() и периодически хостер просить снизить нагрузки )

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.fgets.php

Comment: Нужно знать точную позицию строки в байтах, чтобы можно было пропустить ненужные байты в начале файла

Comment: влейте файлы в БД по строкам, зачем эти приключения с файлами нужны?